# non-cryptographic hash function with output changing just as much as the input

Tags: hash

The way we know (cryptographic) hashes is mostly that they are totally different if the input is changed for just the minimum amount.

```
md5('This is some boring string to test with')    // d546c64928a28b5f605610a919680907
md5('This is another boring string to test with') // a74c1d74da495895bf48056ac979723a
```

Here you see that the hash is totally different, though I only changed one word.

What I'm looking for is a hash function that returns returns an output which is just as similar, as the inputs are similar, and just as different as the inputs are different

```
fn('This is some boring string to test with')     // 00dd2171b47cc2748c2874c42284737
fn('This is another boring string to test with')  // 01ed2371b47cc5748c2874c42284738
fn('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog') // 27bc27999aa2c3c2452cff234feee21
```

See how the first two hashes are quite similar, but the third one is completely different.

I don't want just a simple error-checking mechanism that can detect slight changes though (like CRC). I want to be able to check if two hashes most probably have the a look-a-like origin, by seeing that the hashes are also look-a-likes.

My goal is to understand if it is possible to have hashes of let's say two (actual) fingerprints, and then merely based on the hashes conclude if the original fingerprints probably were from the same finger.

A long time ago I once learned such functions exist.

Can anyone tell me what these types of hashes are named, and what some examples are?

Comment: How is this a topic of information **security**? As the question currently is I'm voting to close it as off-topic. Apart from that have a look at [Locality-sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing).

Comment: why is a hashing algorithm usable for fingerprint recognition, without having to store the original fingerprint, not something for Information Security?

Comment: With this argument everything is something for information security, e.g. asking how to compare strings etc. I think a general question about similarity fingerprints is off-topic while it could be on-topic if the presented problem is not a generalized similarity fingerprint but an actual information security problem which might (or might be not) solved with such similarity fingerprints. A clear description of the use case would also make clear what kind of similarity is actually needed to solve the specific problem.

Comment: I have no idea and this is not related to your question either, i.e. off-topic too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich what stackexchange would you think this question would lie under?? I don't see how this is off topic at all.

Comment: I would say this falls directly under the category of "using cryptography" defined in the help center.

Comment: @MikeSchem: You explicitly ask for properties which you don't want to have in a cryptographic hash function and thus it does not fall under "using cryptography". Since you don't present an actual practical problem you want to solve but more a theoretical one see [Where should I post questions about algorithms: Stack Overflow or Software Engineering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/). Apart from that, have you already looked at locality-sensitive hashing as I have recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there existing hashes that do this.  The reason being when hashes were developed, the requirement that any change in the inputs would create a large change in the output was a basic requirement of a hash.  That being said I can purpose a way to do it.

An example would be a hash that just counts the occurrences of each letter in the input. For simplification let's say this hash only takes lowercase alphabet characters.  So the length of the hash will be 26.  Each position in the hash would refer to a different character. So the first position would total up all the a', the second would hold the total of the b's...

```
hello world
```

would hash to

```
00011001000300200100000000
```

because there are no a's, no b's, no c's, 1 d, ect

a change to

```
hello worlds
```

would hash to

```
00011001000300200110000000
```

The only difference would be the count for the "s".

Obviously there are many problems with this such as you can only have a maximum of 9 instances of each letter, but this is only an example to show how a hash could show small changes in output for small changes in the input.

Comment: I also was thinking of other ways how to make a custom algorithm. But surely one must already exist working out of the box?